# Camera preview on surface view continuos flow

Tags: android

I want to get a preview of the camera on screen (Android Studio), the problem is that I'm in a class which extends a Fragment. I would like to have it on a surface view (with a dimension of about 1/6 of the screen size), in such a way that the preview is always running independently on the surface view while I capture pictures.

The code which take picture is running ok, the only thing that I can't do is to create the independent preview on surface view.

Any idea on how to accomplish that? Given that I'm in a Fragment and I've already created the method `onCreateView`. 
I've searched online but I've only found code for preview plus taking picture.

The idea of what I want to do is the following, but it doesn't work in Fragment unfortunately:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Camera camera; // camera class variable
SurfaceView camView; // drawing camera preview using this variable
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder; // variable to hold surface for surfaceView which means display
boolean camCondition = false;  // conditional variable for camera preview checking and set to false


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // getWindow() to get window and set it's pixel format which is UNKNOWN
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    // refering the id of surfaceView
    camView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    // getting access to the surface of surfaceView and return it to surfaceHolder
    surfaceHolder = camView.getHolder();
    // adding call back to this context means MainActivity
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    // to set surface type
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // stop the camera
    if(camCondition){
        camera.stopPreview(); // stop preview using stopPreview() method
        camCondition = false; // setting camera condition to false means   stop
    }
    // condition to check whether your device have camera or not
    if (camera != null){
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA); //applying effect on camera
            camera.setParameters(parameters); // setting camera parameters
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder); // setting preview of camera
            camera.startPreview();  // starting camera preview

            camCondition = true; // setting camera to true which means  having camera
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();   // opening camera
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);   // setting camera preview  orientation
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();  // stopping camera preview
    camera.release();       // releasing camera
    camera = null;          // setting camera to null when left
    camCondition = false;   // setting camera condition to false also when  exit from application
}



}
```

The xml code is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<org.tensorflow.demo.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<org.tensorflow.demo.RecognitionScoreView
    android:id="@+id/results"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="198dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<org.tensorflow.demo.OverlayView
    android:id="@+id/debug_overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:text="Capture" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:text="Preview" />

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="134dp" />
```

The initial part of code I have in my extended Fragment is the following:

```
public class CameraConnectionFragment extends Fragment {
private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();
/**
* The camera preview size will be chosen to be the smallest frame by pixel   size capable of
* containing a DESIRED_SIZE x DESIRED_SIZE square.
*/
private static final int MINIMUM_PREVIEW_SIZE = 320;

/**
* Conversion from screen rotation to JPEG orientation.
*/
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";
static {
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

/**
* {@link android.view.TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener} handles several  lifecycle events on a
* {@link TextureView}.
*/



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_connection_fragment, container, false);
Button capture = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
Button preview = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
});

  capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


      public void onClick(View v) {
          try {
              captureSession.capture(previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
          }
          catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
              LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
          }

      }
 });

return view;

}
```

What do you think I can do to have a continuos flow of image preview in the surfaceview?

Comment: Can you add any code?

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post.

Comment: Can you please refere this : https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment

Comment: I cannot resolve the Preview class, I don't know why. Moreover, I don't think I can define another class inside the "public class CameraConnectionFragment extends Fragment" am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, getCameraInstance() method can not be resolved and also releaseCameraAndPreview() method, I don't know why.